# count distinct values in single column Python Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

While using and studying the pandas module, i came across the solution to count distinct values in single column via pandas, I have used the below code

```
  #!/bin/python3
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    ## Display Settings
    pd.set_option('display.height', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.width', None)
    pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
    ## Code extraction
    data = pd.read_csv('/home/karn/plura/Test/Python_Pnada/Cyber_July.csv', usecols=['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address', 'Failure reason'])
    hostData = data[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith("CS-Unix-")][data['Safe'].str.contains("^CS-.*DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT$")] [['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address','Failure reason']]
    hostData.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    safeCount = hostData.Safe.value_counts()
    print(safeCount)
```

Output Data for distinct values for column:

```
Safe                

CS-PAR-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT    2
CS-MOS-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT    1
```

Whereas the entire raw data sample of the code is as follows:

```
           Platform ID                   Safe                          Target system address   Failure reason
    1000   CS-Unix-RootAccounts-SSH     CS-PAR-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT                  jjudet      First login - Unable to connect to machine. Ch...
    1003   CS-Unix-RootAccounts-SSH     CS-MOS-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT                  tts126      First login - Unable to connect to machine. Ch...
    1005   CS-Unix-RootAccounts-SSH     CS-PAR-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT                  dccamus      First login - Unable to connect to machine. Ch...
```

Note: Above code all works good, However, if i need to count distinct values from another column which is space delimited such as under **Failure reason** how can we achieve that.

> How to get the following working in this case:

```
safeCount = hostData."Failure reason".value_counts()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to refer to a pandas DataFrame column is:

To return a series:

```
safeCount = hostData["Failure reason"].value_counts()
```

To return a dataframe (i.e. multiple columns):

```
safeCount = hostData[["Failure reason", "Safe"]]
```

And to apply a Series method to a dataFrame:

```
safeCount = hostData[["Failure reason", "Safe"]].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

Comment: look Great. However,if we need to get two columns , can it be adjusted like `safeCount = hostData["Failure reason", "Safe"].value_counts()`

Comment: @pygo Just a side note - you might want to consider using: `data.loc[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith('CS-Unix-') & data['Safe'].str.contains("^CS-.*DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT$"), ['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address', 'Failure reason']]` and take advantage of ANDing boolean arrays instead of creating a new dataframe, then subsetting it again...

Comment: Thnx @Gerardo Flores. However for multiple columns it gives error as `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`

Comment: @JonClements,  is there any link which point a good examples for this as you mentioned.

Comment: @pygo that's because value_counts() is a method for series not dataframe, see my updated answer :)

Comment: @GerardoFlores, thnx :)